# Postgresql executeBatch not working after following mkyong guide

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, try-with-resources

I'm trying to rewrite +/- 250 individual insert statements into 1 batch statement, yet it's not doing anything. no errors, no responses

Have followed this guide:
https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/

After that, many many stackoverflows but I can't see the issue

My local database:

```xml
    <Resource name="jdbc/wtnfV2local" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wtnfV2local"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="postgres" password="geheim" />
```

My not working code:

```java
    @Override
    public void insertArrayUserV2Voidv2(ArrayList<UserV2> users) {
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO RANK (account, rank, date) VALUES (?,?, to_timestamp(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS.ff3\"Z\"'))";
            try (Connection conn = baseDao.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);) {

                for (UserV2 u : users) {
                preparedStmt.setString(1, u.getAccount());
                preparedStmt.setString(2, u.getRank());
                preparedStmt.setString(3, u.getJoined());
                preparedStmt.addBatch();
                System.out.println(preparedStmt);
                }

                System.out.println(conn.getClientInfo());
                preparedStmt.executeBatch();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                if (e.getErrorCode() == 0) {
                } else
                    throw new WebApplicationException(e.getMessage(), Response.Status.CONFLICT);
            }
    }
```

and my previous working code:

```java
    @Override
    public void insertArrayUserV2Void(ArrayList<UserV2> users) {
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO RANK (account, rank, date) VALUES (?,?, to_timestamp(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS.ff3\"Z\"'))";
        for (UserV2 u : users) {
            try (Connection conn = baseDao.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);) {
                preparedStmt.setString(1, u.getAccount());
                preparedStmt.setString(2, u.getRank());
                preparedStmt.setString(3, u.getJoined());
                preparedStmt.execute();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                if (e.getErrorCode() == 0) {
                } else
                    throw new WebApplicationException(e.getMessage(), Response.Status.CONFLICT);
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected result would be +/- 250 insert statements in 1 call, that will try to insert all rows even when PK throws error on 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was working, I just never noticed the error cause I filtered it out without any notifications (stupid me)

also changed the query to:
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO RANK (account, rank, date) VALUES (?,?, to_timestamp(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS.ff3\"Z\"')) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"; so it wouldn't throw an error on the first duplicate from the PK...